# Facing issue while migrating angular 5 to angular 6 in .net core 2.1 project.

Tags: angular, .net-core, visual-studio-2017, angular6, redux-observable

We are using angular SPA template.

Facing issue while migrating angular 5 to angular 6 in .net core 2.1 project.

For now I have updated packages,

**Old version package.json**

```
{
  "name": "projectname",
  "private": true,
  "version": "0.0.0",
  "scripts": {
    "test": "karma start ClientApp/test/karma.conf.js"
  },
  "dependencies": {
    "@angular-redux/form": "^6.7.0",
    "@angular-redux/router": "^6.4.1",
    "@angular-redux/store": "6.6.0",
    "@angular/animations": "^5.2.0",
    "@angular/cli": "^7.1.2",
    "@angular/common": "^5.2.0",
    "@angular/compiler": "^5.2.0",
    "@angular/compiler-cli": "^5.2.0",
    "@angular/core": "^5.2.0",
    "@angular/forms": "^5.2.0",
    "@angular/http": "^5.2.0",
    "@angular/platform-browser": "^5.2.0",
    "@angular/platform-browser-dynamic": "^5.2.0",
    "@angular/platform-server": "^5.2.0",
    "@angular/router": "^5.2.0",
    "@ng-select/ng-select": "0.25.0",
    "@ngtools/webpack": "^1.9.3",
    "@swimlane/ngx-datatable": "^11.3.2",
    "core-js": "^2.4.0",
    "@types/chai": "4.0.1",
    "@types/file-saver": "0.0.1",
    "@types/jasmine": "2.5.53",
    "@types/node": "7.0.18",
    "@types/ramda": "0.25.8",
    "@types/webpack-env": "1.13.0",
    "alasql": "^0.4.5",
    "angular2-multiselect-dropdown": "^2.9.0",
    "angular2-router-loader": "0.3.5",
    "angular2-template-loader": "0.6.2",
    "aspnet-prerendering": "^3.0.1",
    "aspnet-webpack": "^2.0.3",
    "awesome-typescript-loader": "3.2.3",
    "bootstrap": "3.3.7",
    "chai": "4.0.2",
    "css": "^2.2.3",
    "css-loader": "0.28.4",
    "es6-shim": "0.35.3",
    "event-source-polyfill": "0.0.9",
    "expose-loader": "0.7.3",
    "extract-text-webpack-plugin": "3.0.2",
    "file-loader": "0.11.2",
    "file-saver": "^1.3.3",
    "flux-standard-action": "^1.2.0",
    "font-awesome": "^4.7.0",
    "isomorphic-fetch": "2.2.1",
    "jquery": "3.2.1",
    "ng-trim-value-accessor": "^2.0.2",
    "ngx-bootstrap": "^1.6.6",
    "ngx-cookie-service": "^1.0.10",
    "powerbi-client": "^2.6.0",
    "preboot": "4.5.2",
    "ramda": "^0.23.0",
    "raw-loader": "0.5.1",
    "redux": "^3.7.0",
    "redux-devtools-extension": "2.13.2",
    "redux-logger": "^3.0.1",
    "redux-observable": "^0.16.0",
    "reflect-metadata": "0.1.10",
    "rxjs": "^5.5.7",
    "style-loader": "0.18.2",
    "to-string-loader": "1.1.5",
    "ts-node": "^7.0.0",
    "ts-xlsx": "0.0.11",
    "typescript": "^2.4.2",
    "url-loader": "^1.0.1",
    "webpack": "^3.0.0",
    "webpack-hot-middleware": "2.18.2",
    "webpack-merge": "4.1.0",
    "zone.js": "0.8.12"
  },
  "devDependencies": {
    "html-loader": "^0.4.5",
    "jasmine-core": "^2.99.1",
    "json-loader": "0.5.4",
    "webpack-cli": "^3.1.0"
  }
}
```

**New version package.json**

```
{
  "name": "projectname",
  "private": true,
  "version": "0.0.0",
  "scripts": {
    "test": "karma start ClientApp/test/karma.conf.js"
  },
  "dependencies": {
    "@angular-redux/form": "^9.0.0",
    "@angular-redux/router": "^9.0.0",
    "@angular-redux/store": "9.0.0",
    "@angular/animations": "^6.0.3",
    "@angular/cli": "^7.1.3",
    "@angular/common": "^6.0.3",
    "@angular/compiler": "^6.0.3",
    "@angular/compiler-cli": "^6.0.3",
    "@angular/core": "^6.0.3",
    "@angular/forms": "^6.0.3",
    "@angular/http": "^6.0.3",
    "@angular/platform-browser": "^6.0.3",
    "@angular/platform-browser-dynamic": "^6.0.3",
    "@angular/platform-server": "^6.0.3",
    "@angular/router": "^6.0.3",
    "@ng-select/ng-select": "2.1.0",
    "@ngtools/webpack": "^6.0.5",
    "@swimlane/ngx-datatable": "^13.0.0",
    "@types/chai": "4.1.3",
    "@types/file-saver": "1.3.0",
    "@types/jasmine": "2.8.7",
    "@types/node": "10.1.3",
    "@types/ramda": "0.25.8",
    "@types/webpack-env": "1.13.6",
    "ajv": "6.0.0",
    "alasql": "^0.4.5",
    "angular2-multiselect-dropdown": "^2.9.0",
    "angular2-router-loader": "0.3.5",
    "angular2-template-loader": "0.6.2",
    "aspnet-prerendering": "^3.0.1",
    "aspnet-webpack": "^3.0.0",
    "awesome-typescript-loader": "5.0.0",
    "bootstrap": "3.3.7",
    "chai": "4.0.2",
    "core-js": "^2.5.6",
    "css": "^2.2.3",
    "css-loader": "0.28.11",
    "es6-shim": "0.35.3",
    "event-source-polyfill": "0.0.9",
    "expose-loader": "0.7.3",
    "file-loader": "0.11.2",
    "file-saver": "^1.3.3",
    "flux-standard-action": "^2.0.2",
    "font-awesome": "^4.7.0",
    "isomorphic-fetch": "2.2.1",
    "jquery": "3.2.1",
    "mini-css-extract-plugin": "0.4.2",
    "ng-trim-value-accessor": "^2.0.2",
    "ngx-bootstrap": "^1.6.6",
    "ngx-cookie-service": "^1.0.10",
    "powerbi-client": "^2.6.0",
    "preboot": "4.5.2",
    "ramda": "^0.23.0",
    "raw-loader": "0.5.1",
    "redux": "^4.0.0",
    "redux-devtools-extension": "2.13.5",
    "redux-logger": "^3.0.6",
    "redux-observable": "^1.0.0",
    "reflect-metadata": "0.1.10",
    "rxjs": "^6.2.1",
    "style-loader": "0.18.2",
    "to-string-loader": "1.1.5",
    "ts-node": "^7.0.0",
    "ts-xlsx": "0.0.11",
    "tslint": "^5.0.0",
    "typescript": "^2.8.1",
    "rxjs-tslint": "0.1.5",
    "url-loader": "^1.0.1",
    "webpack": "^4.16.0",
    "webpack-dev-middleware": "^3.0.0",
    "webpack-hot-middleware": "2.21.0",
    "webpack-merge": "4.1.2",
    "zone.js": "0.8.26"
  },
  "devDependencies": {
    "html-loader": "^0.4.5",
    "jasmine-core": "^2.99.1",
    "json-loader": "0.5.4",
    "webpack-cli": "^3.1.2"
  }
}
```

Then executed following commands to update rxjs breaking changes

> npm install -g rxjs-tslint rxjs-5-to-6-migrate -p ./tsconfig.app.json

**Now facing following issue :**

```
One or more errors occurred. (Dll Reference Plugin Invalid Options

options.manifest.content['./node_modules/rxjs/Observable.js']['meta'] is an invalid additional property
options.manifest.content['./node_modules/rxjs/Subscriber.js']['meta'] is an invalid additional property
options.manifest.content['./node_modules/jquery/dist/jquery.js']['meta'] is an invalid additional property
options.manifest.content['./node_modules/@angular/core/@angular/core.es5.js']['meta'] is an invalid additional property
options.manifest.content['./node_modules/tslib/tslib.es6.js']['meta'] is an invalid additional property
options.manifest.content['./node_modules/rxjs/util/root.js']['meta'] is an invalid additional property
options.manifest.content['./node_modules/@angular/platform-browser/@angular/platform-browser.es5.js']['meta'] is an invalid additional property
options.manifest.content['./node_modules/rxjs/Subject.js']['meta'] is an invalid additional property
options.manifest.content['./node_modules/webpack/buildin/global.js']['meta'] is an invalid additional property
options.manifest.content['./node_modules/@angular/common/@angular/common.es5.js']['meta'] is an invalid additional property
options.manifest.content['./node_modules/rxjs/Subscription.js']['meta'] is an invalid additional property
options.manifest.content['./node_modules/rxjs/observable/EmptyObservable.js']['meta'] is an invalid additional property
options.manifest.content['./node_modules/rxjs/OuterSubscriber.js']['meta'] is an invalid additional property
options.manifest.content['./node_modules/rxjs/observable/ArrayObservable.js']['meta'] is an invalid additional property
options.manifest.content['./node_modules/rxjs/operators/mergeAll.js']['meta'] is an invalid additional property
options.manifest.content['./node_modules/rxjs/operators/mergeMap.js']['meta'] is an invalid additional property
options.manifest.content['./node_modules/rxjs/symbol/iterator.js']['meta'] is an invalid additional property
options.manifest.content['./node_modules/rxjs/symbol/observable.js']['meta'] is an invalid additional property
options.manifest.content['./node_modules/rxjs/symbol/rxSubscriber.js']['meta'] is an invalid additional property
options.manifest.content['./node_modules/rxjs/util/EmptyError.js']['meta'] is an invalid additional property
options.manifest.content['./node_modules/rxjs/util/isArray.js']['meta'] is an invalid additional property
options.manifest.content['./node_modules/rxjs/util/subscribeToResult.js']['meta'] is an invalid additional property
options.manifest.content['./node_modules/@angular/compiler/@angular/compiler.es5.js']['meta'] is an invalid additional property
options.manifest.content['./ClientApp async recursive']['meta'] is an invalid additional property
options.manifest.content['./node_modules/process/browser.js']['meta'] is an invalid additional property
options.manifest.content['./node_modules/rxjs/Observer.js']['meta'] is an invalid additional property
options.manifest.content['./node_modules/rxjs/observable/PromiseObservable.js']['meta'] is an invalid additional property
options.manifest.content['./node_modules/rxjs/observable/ScalarObservable.js']['meta'] is an invalid additional property
options.manifest.content['./node_modules/rxjs/observable/fromPromise.js']['meta'] is an invalid additional property
options.manifest.content['./node_modules/rxjs/operator/map.js']['meta'] is an invalid additional property
options.manifest.content['./node_modules/rxjs/operators/refCount.js']['meta'] is an invalid additional property
options.manifest.content['./node_modules/rxjs/util/ObjectUnsubscribedError.js']['meta'] is an invalid additional property
options.manifest.content['./node_modules/rxjs/util/errorObject.js']['meta'] is an invalid additional property
options.manifest.content['./node_modules/rxjs/util/isArrayLike.js']['meta'] is an invalid additional property
options.manifest.content['./node_modules/rxjs/util/isFunction.js']['meta'] is an invalid additional property
options.manifest.content['./node_modules/rxjs/util/isObject.js']['meta'] is an invalid additional property
options.manifest.content['./node_modules/rxjs/util/isPromise.js']['meta'] is an invalid additional property
options.manifest.content['./node_modules/rxjs/util/isScheduler.js']['meta'] is an invalid additional property
options.manifest.content['./node_modules/rxjs/util/pipe.js']['meta'] is an invalid additional property
options.manifest.content['./node_modules/@angular/animations/@angular/animations.es5.js']['meta'] is an invalid additional property
options.manifest.content['./node_modules/@angular/forms/@angular/forms.es5.js']['meta'] is an invalid additional property
options.manifest.content['./node_modules/@angular/http/@angular/http.es5.js']['meta'] is an invalid additional property
options.manifest.content['./node_modules/@angular/platform-browser-dynamic/@angular/platform-browser-dynamic.es5.js']['meta'] is an invalid additional property
options.manifest.content['./node_modules/@angular/router/@angular/router.es5.js']['meta'] is an invalid additional property
options.manifest.content['./node_modules/bootstrap/dist/js/npm.js']['meta'] is an invalid additional property
options.manifest.content['./node_modules/es6-promise/dist/es6-promise.js']['meta'] is an invalid additional property
options.manifest.content['./node_modules/es6-shim/es6-shim.js']['meta'] is an invalid additional property
options.manifest.content['./node_modules/event-source-polyfill/eventsource.js']['meta'] is an invalid additional property
options.manifest.content['./node_modules/@swimlane/ngx-datatable/release/assets/icons.css']['meta'] is an invalid additional property
options.manifest.content['./node_modules/@swimlane/ngx-datatable/release/index.css']['meta'] is an invalid additional property
options.manifest.content['./node_modules/@swimlane/ngx-datatable/release/themes/material.css']['meta'] is an invalid additional property
options.manifest.content['./node_modules/bootstrap/dist/css/bootstrap.css']['meta'] is an invalid additional property
options.manifest.content['./node_modules/font-awesome/css/font-awesome.css']['meta'] is an invalid additional property
options.manifest.content['./node_modules/zone.js/dist/zone.js']['meta'] is an invalid additional property
options.manifest.content['./node_modules/bootstrap/js/affix.js']['meta'] is an invalid additional property
options.manifest.content['./node_modules/bootstrap/js/alert.js']['meta'] is an invalid additional property
options.manifest.content['./node_modules/bootstrap/js/button.js']['meta'] is an invalid additional property
options.manifest.content['./node_modules/bootstrap/js/carousel.js']['meta'] is an invalid additional property
options.manifest.content['./node_modules/bootstrap/js/collapse.js']['meta'] is an invalid additional property
options.manifest.content['./node_modules/bootstrap/js/dropdown.js']['meta'] is an invalid additional property
options.manifest.content['./node_modules/bootstrap/js/modal.js']['meta'] is an invalid additional property
options.manifest.content['./node_modules/bootstrap/js/popover.js']['meta'] is an invalid additional property
options.manifest.content['./node_modules/bootstrap/js/scrollspy.js']['meta'] is an invalid additional property
options.manifest.content['./node_modules/bootstrap/js/tab.js']['meta'] is an invalid additional property
options.manifest.content['./node_modules/bootstrap/js/tooltip.js']['meta'] is an invalid additional property
options.manifest.content['./node_modules/bootstrap/js/transition.js']['meta'] is an invalid additional property
options.manifest.content['./node_modules/rxjs/BehaviorSubject.js']['meta'] is an invalid additional property
options.manifest.content['./node_modules/rxjs/InnerSubscriber.js']['meta'] is an invalid additional property
options.manifest.content['./node_modules/rxjs/Notification.js']['meta'] is an invalid additional property
options.manifest.content['./node_modules/rxjs/SubjectSubscription.js']['meta'] is an invalid additional property
options.manifest.content['./node_modules/rxjs/observable/ArrayLikeObservable.js']['meta'] is an invalid additional property
options.manifest.content['./node_modules/rxjs/observable/ConnectableObservable.js']['meta'] is an invalid additional property
options.manifest.content['./node_modules/rxjs/observable/ForkJoinObservable.js']['meta'] is an invalid additional property
options.manifest.content['./node_modules/rxjs/observable/FromObservable.js']['meta'] is an invalid additional property
options.manifest.content['./node_modules/rxjs/observable/IteratorObservable.js']['meta'] is an invalid additional property
options.manifest.content['./node_modules/rxjs/observable/forkJoin.js']['meta'] is an invalid additional property
options.manifest.content['./node_modules/rxjs/observable/from.js']['meta'] is an invalid additional property
options.manifest.content['./node_modules/rxjs/observable/merge.js']['meta'] is an invalid additional property
options.manifest.content['./node_modules/rxjs/observable/of.js']['meta'] is an invalid additional property
options.manifest.content['./node_modules/rxjs/operator/catch.js']['meta'] is an invalid additional property
options.manifest.content['./node_modules/rxjs/operator/concatAll.js']['meta'] is an invalid additional property
options.manifest.content['./node_modules/rxjs/operator/concatMap.js']['meta'] is an invalid additional property
options.manifest.content['./node_modules/rxjs/operator/every.js']['meta'] is an invalid additional property
options.manifest.content['./node_modules/rxjs/operator/filter.js']['meta'] is an invalid additional property
options.manifest.content['./node_modules/rxjs/operator/first.js']['meta'] is an invalid additional property
options.manifest.content['./node_modules/rxjs/operator/last.js']['meta'] is an invalid additional property
options.manifest.content['./node_modules/rxjs/operator/mergeAll.js']['meta'] is an invalid additional property
options.manifest.content['./node_modules/rxjs/operator/mergeMap.js']['meta'] is an invalid additional property
options.manifest.content['./node_modules/rxjs/operator/reduce.js']['meta'] is an invalid additional property
options.manifest.content['./node_modules/rxjs/operator/share.js']['meta'] is an invalid additional property
options.manifest.content['./node_modules/rxjs/operators/catchError.js']['meta'] is an invalid additional property
options.manifest.content['./node_modules/rxjs/operators/concatAll.js']['meta'] is an invalid additional property
options.manifest.content['./node_modules/rxjs/operators/concatMap.js']['meta'] is an invalid additional property
options.manifest.content['./node_modules/rxjs/operators/defaultIfEmpty.js']['meta'] is an invalid additional property
options.manifest.content['./node_modules/rxjs/operators/every.js']['meta'] is an invalid additional property
options.manifest.content['./node_modules/rxjs/operators/filter.js']['meta'] is an invalid additional property
options.manifest.content['./node_modules/rxjs/operators/first.js']['meta'] is an invalid additional property
options.manifest.content['./node_modules/rxjs/operators/last.js']['meta'] is an invalid additional property
options.manifest.content['./node_modules/rxjs/operators/map.js']['meta'] is an invalid additional property
options.manifest.content['./node_modules/rxjs/operators/multicast.js']['meta'] is an invalid additional property
options.manifest.content['./node_modules/rxjs/operators/observeOn.js']['meta'] is an invalid additional property
options.manifest.content['./node_modules/rxjs/operators/reduce.js']['meta'] is an invalid additional property
options.manifest.content['./node_modules/rxjs/operators/scan.js']['meta'] is an invalid additional property
options.manifest.content['./node_modules/rxjs/operators/share.js']['meta'] is an invalid additional property
options.manifest.content['./node_modules/rxjs/operators/takeLast.js']['meta'] is an invalid additional property
options.manifest.content['./node_modules/rxjs/util/ArgumentOutOfRangeError.js']['meta'] is an invalid additional property
options.manifest.content['./node_modules/rxjs/util/UnsubscriptionError.js']['meta'] is an invalid additional property
options.manifest.content['./node_modules/rxjs/util/identity.js']['meta'] is an invalid additional property
options.manifest.content['./node_modules/rxjs/util/noop.js']['meta'] is an invalid additional property
options.manifest.content['./node_modules/rxjs/util/toSubscriber.js']['meta'] is an invalid additional property
options.manifest.content['./node_modules/rxjs/util/tryCatch.js']['meta'] is an invalid additional property
options.manifest.content should match some schema in anyOf
options.manifest should be string
options.manifest should match exactly one schema in oneOf
options['manifest'] is an invalid additional property
options.content is a required property
options should match some schema in anyOf

ValidationError: Dll Reference Plugin Invalid Options
```

Comment: Rxjs got an update with 6.0 you might want to look into this: https://www.academind.com/learn/javascript/rxjs-6-what-changed/

Answer (score -1):

Please, did you get an answer to this issue?  I am experiencing the exact same thing.

I believe this might be do to the webpack version upgrade:

v1.9 to v4.0
webpack.config.js

```
    plugins: [
        new webpack.DllReferencePlugin({
            context: __dirname,
            manifest: require('./wwwroot/dist/vendor-manifest.json')
        })
    ]
```